# How to create comments system with replies limit in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help! I need to create comments system with multilevel replies limitation. It means that I need to use LIMIT on comments where is parentId.

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.comment_text, gc.created_at, gc.parent,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("id", gc1.id, "comment_text", gc1.comment_text, "created_at", gc1.created_at)) as sub_comments
FROM games_comments as gc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gc.id, gc.comment_text, gc.parent, gc.created_at FROM games_comments as gc ORDER BY gc.created_at DESC) as gc1 ON gc.id = gc1.parent
WHERE gc.parent = 0
GROUP BY gc.id
ORDER BY gc.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

This is only way, I know to get replies, but only 1 level and without any LIMIT.

Table:

```
╔═══╦════════╦══════════╗
║id ║ comment║ parent_id║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════╣
║ 1 ║ text1  ║    0     ║
║ 2 ║ text2  ║    0     ║
║ 3 ║ text3  ║    2     ║
║ 4 ║ text4  ║    2     ║
║ 5 ║ text5  ║    2     ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════╝
```

And now I need to get result like

```
var result = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "text1",
        "replies": [

        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "text2",
        "replies": [ (with LIMIT 0,2)
            {
                "id": 3,
                "text": "text3"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "text": "text4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, there is LIMIT 0,2

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Could you please give your table structure details and your requirements?

Comment: So I edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set limit condition in Left Join sub query.

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.comment_text, gc.created_at, gc.parent,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("id", gc1.id, "comment_text", gc1.comment_text, "created_at", gc1.created_at)) as sub_comments
FROM games_comments as gc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gc.id, gc.comment_text, gc.parent, gc.created_at FROM games_comments as gc ORDER BY gc.created_at DESC LIMIT 0,5) as gc1 ON gc.id = gc1.parent
WHERE gc.parent = 0
GROUP BY gc.id
ORDER BY gc.created_at DESC
```

Try this query.

Based on your demo table, I have created this query which is working fine as per your requirement. **Below is a sample query which I tested.**

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.comment, gc.parent_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("id", gc1.id, "comment", gc1.comment)) as sub_comments
FROM test as gc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gc.id, gc.comment, gc.parent_id FROM test as gc 
           ORDER BY gc.id DESC LIMIT 0,2) as gc1 ON gc.id = gc1.parent_id
WHERE gc.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY gc.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I tried it already but someho it doesn't work, but now its working. Thank you !

Comment: I had to change ORDER BY gc.created_at to ORDER BY gc.id in JOIN