# MySQL Query For Comments & Replies - With LIMIT on both

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a comments system like facebook, where users can submit comments on posts. At the same time, users will be able to reply to comments. This comments table is going to have millions of rows, so the MySQL query needs to be efficient.

**Requirements:**

- I only need 1 level of replies, no huge reply nests, nothing fancy.
- When the page loads, I only want 10 comments showing (parentid = 0).
- For each comment, I only want 5 replies to show up (parentid > 0)
- I will need a count of each, so I can add a "show more" button if there are more comments/replies still left to read.
- The comments/replies need to be JOINED with my users and profileimages table to bring up usernames and other profile info.

My "comments" table is set up like (id, userid, postid, parentid, comment, timestamp)

My "users" able is set up like (id, username, profileimageid)

My "profileimages" table is set up like (id, path)

So far, I have this mess like:

```
SELECT gc.id, gc.postid, gc.comment, gc.parentid, gc.userid, users.username, profileimages.path,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', gc1.id, 'text', gc1.comment, 'userid', gc1.userid, 'username', gc1.username, 'path', gc1.path)) as sub_comments 
FROM comments as gc JOIN users ON gc.userid = users.id JOIN profileimages ON users.profileimageid = profileimages.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gc.id, gc.comment, gc.parentid, gc.userid, users.username, profileimages.path FROM comments as gc JOIN users ON gc.userid = users.id JOIN profileimages ON users.profileimageid = profileimages.id ORDER BY gc.id DESC LIMIT 0,5) as gc1 ON gc.id = gc1.parentid 
WHERE gc.postid = 1 AND gc.parentid = 0 GROUP BY gc.id LIMIT 10
```

This is something I "Frankenstein'ed" from studying a related topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219927/how-to-create-comments-system-with-replies-limit-in-mariadb) and on Google. (The CONCAT/JSON_OBJECT isn't required for me, it was required for that other guy, but I can still use it if it turns out to be useful). The query I have now is big, ugly, inefficient on large tables and I can't sort the replies using "ACS", it's stuck only working on "DESC", and no count figures for the comments and replies either. There's gotta be a better way. I would prefer not having to loop MySQL queries in PHP to get each set of replies for each comment (unless that is the way to do it for this setup).

Edit: This does not have to be one giant query, just an efficient way to do this with a giant table and PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I will `NOT` use a **single** query to do everything.

Comment: @kenlee how would you do it?

Comment: It’s OK to create a loop in php, in fact, multiple loops. The outer loop for the comment - then pass the comment I’d into a nested inner loop for the replies - output the JSON response using both result sets from the loops. When you click load more, pass in the comment or reply ID to a dedicated query on the server side. Utilize OFFSET in SQL to get the records starting from row 5 (to ignore the previously retrieved records). As for the reply counts you can create a view to query from with a COUNT of replies or utilize triggers to fill in dedicated count columns in the comment/reply table.

Comment: @GRIV thanks for the advice, that was pretty much was I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if that would be the best way or that is how facebook and twitter do it with huge tables. I guess it's probably not too bad with indexes, as long as I have those LIMIT set for looping.

Comment: No problem. As long as your indexes are properly setup, it shouldn’t be a problem and limiting your data always helps with response times. Utilizing OFFSET can help as well so you don’t retrieve the same rows twice on your load more button.